# ¿Cómo formar una flecha con css?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Estimados mi consulta es la siguiente, necesito formar una flecha con el `<span>` que esta en el siguiente código y que tiene una clase `.titulos-panel`, lo que necesito es cortar la parte inferior derecha del elemento, como se muestra en la siguiente imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```css
.titulos-panel {
    background: linear-gradient(30deg, transparent 0%, #FF5252 0%,#FF5252 90%,transparent 5%);
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="col-md-6">
<div class="list-group">
  <span href="#" class="list-group-item titulos-panel">
      <h6 class="list-group-item-heading">PROSPECTOS</h6>
  </span>
</div>
</div>
```

Muchas Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yo lo soluciono de la siguiente manera:

```css
.flecha {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  height: 80px;
  width: 240px;
  border: solid 1px #ccc;
  border-right: none;
  background: #eee linear-gradient(white, #f1f1f1 37%, #e1e1e1 57%, #f6f6f6);
}

.flecha:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 16px;
  right: -25px;
  width: 48px;
  height: 47px;
  border-left: solid 1px #ccc;
  border-top: solid 1px #ccc;
  transform: rotate(134deg) skewX(-10deg) skewY(-10deg);
  background: #eee linear-gradient(45deg, white, #f1f1f1 37%, #e1e1e1 57%, #f6f6f6);
  content: '';
}
```

```html
<div class='flecha'>PROSPECTOS</div>
```

Comment: Sin entrar en discusiones, creo que aportar la solución con un código totalmente distinto al mostrado por el OP no es lo más correcto. Tampoco digo que le demos el código para que haga copy/paste, y aunque tu ejemplo funciona perfectamente, me parece más acertada la respuesta de @MauCano en acercarse (aunque no sea en forma) a lo que pregunta el OP

Answer (score 3):

Para realizar lo que necesitas, necesitas 3 elementos, tal vez menos, pero esta es una forma de hacerlo, espero te ayude.

```css
.flecha-container {
 position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 600px;
    height: 400px;
}

.text{
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid red;
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
  padding: 2rem;
  margin-top: 2rem;
  width: 50%;
}
.flecha {
 width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 60px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 60px solid transparent;
    border-left: 60px solid red;
    position: absolute;
    right: 175px;
    top: -15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flecha-container">
  <span class="text"> soy una flecha </span>
  <span class="flecha"> </span>
</div>
```

Puedes jugar con los valores y obtener el resultado que buscas.

Answer (score 3):

Complementaria:

- ejemplo de reemplazar los estilos del bootstrap (bordes redondeados, alto de línea) para primer y último ítem del list group
- uso de rem en vez de píxeles para acomodarse al bootstrap
- la magia del triángulo explicada

```css
.titulos-panel,
.list-group-item.titulos-panel {
  background-color: #FF5252;
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 3.5rem;
  line-height: 4rem;
  height: 4rem;
  border: medium none;
  /* se pierde el borde ver otra respuesta */
}

.list-group-item.titulos-panel>h6 {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  line-height: 2rem;
  /* alto y margenes del título */
}

.list-group-item.titulos-panel:first-child {
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
  /* quitar redondeado del borde derecho */
}

.list-group-item.titulos-panel:last-child {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  /* quitar redondeado del borde derecho */
}

/* triángulo after */
.titulos-panel:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: " ";
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 2rem solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 2rem solid transparent;
  border-right: 2rem solid transparent;
  border-left: 3rem solid #FF5252;
}

/* triángulo en pixels */
.flecha-derecha {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 30px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 30px solid transparent;
  border-right: 30px solid transparent;
  border-left: 30px solid #FF5252;
}

/* cada borde con su color */
.magia-de-flechas {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 30px solid green;
  border-bottom: 30px solid blue;
  border-right: 30px solid yellow;
  border-left: 30px solid red;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="list-group">
    <span href="#" class="list-group-item  titulos-panel">
      <h6 class="list-group-item-heading">PROSPECTOS</h6>
  </span>
    <span href="#" class="list-group-item  titulos-panel">
      <h6 class="list-group-item-heading">PROSPECTOS 2</h6>
  </span>
    <span href="#" class="list-group-item  titulos-panel">
      <h6 class="list-group-item-heading">PROSPECTOS 3</h6>
  </span>
  </div>
</div>
<hr/>
<h6 class="titulos-panel">PROSPECTOS</h6>

<hr/>
<div class="flecha-derecha"></div>

<hr/>
<div class="magia-de-flechas"></div>
```